# Is there any such thing as a non-nested hierarchy?

Tags: hierarchy-theorems

(I didn't see any question like this on the CSTheory exchange -- apologies if it has already been answered.)

In a nested hierarchy, a higher level includes all levels below it.

The classic example of a "non-nested" hierarchy is military rank.  A general is not a lieutenant, so military rank is a non-nested hierarchy.

But here's my objection -- doesn't a general have all the skills a lieutenant has, plus more skills?  So in that sense, isn't every general a lieutenant?  He may not be called "lieutenant", but in reality he is a lieutenant-plus.

Thus, I am wondering... can we really say that any hierarchy is non-nested?

Comment: This seems off-topic unless you add a connection to research-level theoretical computer science.

Comment: I thought from the title it was going to ask about hierarchies like PH or the W-hierarchy, and whether there are analogous hierarchies that aren't linearly ordered...

Comment: Sorry guys - I’ll try to move this question to the StackExchange for the English language (or for Math).  I’m a data wrangler rather than a true CS person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is more about the semantics of the english language than about cs theory. Unless this has a connection to some problem. I think generally speaking, hierarchy of *things* just means there is a well ordered relation of these *things*. And nested just means that the *things* are nested within each other. The relation is defined based on nesting. So the military ranks are a hierarchy, but not a nested one because the groups aren't nested within each other.

Comment: Thanks @styopa !  Can I ask a quick follow-up…
A, B, C, and D are sets.  
A includes B.
B includes C and D.
Thus, for nesting-level:
A = 0.
B = 1.
C = 2.
D = 2.
Nesting-level is a total order on A, but it is not a well-order because not every subset of A has a least element.  
A is nested, but can we call it a hierarchy?

Comment: From the definition of hierarchy I've seen most, I wouldn't call it a hierarchy. However, I don't think this matters for any practical purposes. You could just make a small note before calling it a hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you so much!    @styopa